# Return List of Records where 1 ID is linked to 2 different PKs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

First of all, apologies for the title - wasn't sure how to word it.

Essentially I have this data:

| ID | RuleID | AccountID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | ABC001 |
| 2 | 5678 | DEF001 |
| 3 | 1234 | GHI001 |
| 4 | 1234 | ABC001 |

I want to be able to return all rows where the **RuleID** is matched to 2 distinct **AccountID**'s, with the data in this table, a single **RuleID** should only be linked to a single **AccountID** - if it's shared then there's a problem.

I have tried using code such as this:

```
SELECT *
FROM #rules
GROUP BY RuleID, AccountID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

and trying to change it to work with matching how I want, however, I can't get it to work.

Thank you.

Comment: Try `select ruleid, count(distinct accountid) from table group by ruleid having count(distinct accountid) > 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM #rules r
where exists 
  (select 1 from #rules rr
    where rr.RuleID = r.RuleID and rr.AccountID <> r.AccountID);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT RuleID
FROM #rules
GROUP BY RuleID
HAVING COUNT(distinct AccountID) > 1
```

or

```
SELECT RuleID
FROM #rules
GROUP BY RuleID
HAVING min(AccountID) != max(AccountID)
```